# How can I get Nvidia Geforce Shadow Play screen recording working on Windows Server 2012 r2?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, windows-server-2012-r2

I've installed 2012 r2 as a clean install.

I installed the latest win 7/8.1 x64 drivers from nvidia:
375.70-desktop-win8-win7-64bit-international-whql
from here,

Since version 373 for nvidia, a new geforce now controls shadow play.

So making sure the directory is set correctly, pressing alt+f9 to record, it sais Recording has started and when pressing alt+f9 it sais the Recording has been saved but no .mp4 is created in the directory at any point.

I tried downloading an older version of the drivers:
http://www.guru3d.com/files-get/geforce-372-90-whql-driver-download,3.html

These drivers are before the new geforce, same problem, it sais it is recording but no file is created in the set directory.

I have turned off Advanced IE Security Configuration in Server Manager.

There must be a reason the file is not created. It is a clean install of Server 2012 r2, this must be a known problem, I'm surprised no one has discussed this.

Shadow play is not something I want to give away at the expense of using Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Newer geforce drivers do now work with windows server 2012r2 and windows server 2016.

Comment: It might be useful to give a rough idea of what's a minimal version that would work